Debugging ts CDK project in VSC
Is there a proper way to debug CDK applications in Visual Studio Code?
I'm trying to run the debugger and getting an undefined value from the cdk.json context property.
cdk.ts:
const app = new cdk.App();
const configFromContext = app.node.tryGetContext('some_value'); // configFromContext is undefined

launch.json:
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch CDK",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "./node_modules/ts-node/register/transpile-only",
            ],
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/bin/cdk.ts",
            ],
        },
    ]

I've tried passing the cdk.json as a argument for the cdk cli context command but it didn't work.

Here is an example of the launch.json I have been using:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "CDK Debugger",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my-cdk-app", // path to your cdk app folder with node_modules and cdk.json
            "program": "./node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "synth"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I have mixed results with the runtime args transpile-only option. I also can not seem to get breakpoints working in my vscode, it was working for me before. I have now resorted to console.log(val) statements, so you can do something like this in cdk.ts:
console.log(`configFromContext: ${configFromContext}`)

Let me know if this works for you :)

You need to pass the context with its value. For example in your case:
const configFromContext = app.node.tryGetContext('some_value');

# cli
> cdk synth -c some_value=value

Or you can add that in cdk.json
# cdk.json
{
  "app": "npx ts-node bin/cdk-workshop.ts",
  "context": {
      "my_context_key": "my_context_value",
  }
}

# usage:
const configFromContext = app.node.tryGetContext('my_context_key');

It is undefined because the context you are trying to get doesn't exist.

(method) def try_get_context(key: str) -> Any
Retrieves a value from tree context.
Context is usually initialized at the root, but can be overridden at
any point in the tree.
:param key: The context key.
:return: The context value or undefined
if there is no context value for this key.

